# Retrieve single object Firebase Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angularfire

I'm working on this application but I'm having problems retrieving the object's entire information.

I have a "news" page that will display all the lists from the DB, that one is working fine, when you click on the news, it will take you to the "details" page, I can do the routing, no problem.

The issue is that I can't get the data from Firebase. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

**Component:**

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NewsService } from '../news.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-display',
  templateUrl: './display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./display.component.css']
})
export class NewsDisplayComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('closeBtn') closeBtn: ElementRef;
  id;

  news: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private route: ActivatedRoute, private newsService: NewsService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.news = this.newsService.getSingleNews(this.id).valueChanges();
    console.log(this.news);
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.router.navigate(['/news']);
    this.closeBtn.nativeElement.click();
  }

}
```

**Service.ts**

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { News } from './news.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class NewsService {
    news: AngularFireList<News[]>;
    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    }
    getNews() {
        this.news = this.db.list('news');
        return this.news.valueChanges();
    }

    getSingleNews(id: string) {
        return this.db.object('news' + id);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">{{ id }}</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" #closeBtn (click)="closeModal()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h1>{{ news.title | async }}</h1>
        <h2>{{ news.subtitle | async }}</h2>
        <p>{{ news.article | async}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

**Component**

```
this.newsService.getSingleNews(this.id).subscribe(news => {
    this.news = news
});
```

**Service.ts**

It seems like you're missing a slash after news.

```
getSingleNews(id: string) {
    return this.db.object('news/' + id);
}
```

**Update:**

Change `news: Observable<any>` property to an object. If you do it the way I showed you it isn't an observable anymore.

Comment: Hey ams. Thanks! I didn't work. I got the samething. Nothing shows. :(

Comment: Have you changed the `news: Observable<any>` property to an object? because if you do it the way I showed you it isn't an observable anymore.  Also what does the data `news` from the subscription show when you console.log it.

Comment: @iconio Nice to hear! Could you mark my answer as the correct one, so that other people in the future with the same problem will see that this solution works?

Comment: For me, the `getSingleNews()` method needs to `return this.db.object('news/' + id).valueChanges();`